# Help showing that u is harmonic.

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I know that u is a continuous function where

$$u(x_0) $$ is equal to the average over the surface of all balls centered at a point $x_0$.

How would I show that this function is harmonic, or approach this problem. Would I find a harmonic function $f$ which is equal to $u$ on the boundary and just do something with the strong maximum principle?

Comment: Please look hera: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/534111/mean-value-property-implies-harmonicity

Comment: Do you know this for only a *single point* $x_0$? In that case, it's not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is relevant. Indeed, you restrict yourself in a closed ball contained in the open set and construct a function $f$ which is harmonic in the open ball and which agrees with $u$ in the boundary of the ball. This is done by the Poisson integral. Once this is done, you use the mean property of $u$ to prove that $u = f$. Since Harmonicity is obviously a local property, this gives you the conclusion.

This is done in Walter Rudin, Real and Complex analysis. Check Theorem 11.16, page 230.